# How to solve poset question?

Tags: relations

In a poset $P = (S,\leq)$, we say that a chain is any sequence $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k$ of distinct elements in $S$,such that $x_1\leq x_2\leq\ldots\leq x_k$.

For example, consider the poset $P = (P(A),\subseteq)$, where $A = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. One example of a chain here could be the sequence $\emptyset$, $\{2, 5\}$, $\{1, 2, 5\}$, $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, because $$\emptyset\subseteq \{2, 5\} \subseteq \{1,2,5\} \subseteq \{1,2,3,4,5\}.$$
So, the question is...
What is the largest number of elements you can have in a chain, in the poset $P = (P(A),\subseteq)$ defined in this problem? Prove that your claim is correct.

Comment: It would have been a much more interesting if we allow $|A|=\kappa$ to be any cardinal, instead of restricting it to a finite number.

Comment: @Arthur the interestingness is that for finite $n$ the answer is $n+1$ whereas for infinite $\kappa$ [the answer is $2^\kappa$](https://mathoverflow.net/a/122033/91375)...

Comment: @KennyLau You're right, that is interesting. At any rate, i believe that keeping things finite will be enough for this question.

Comment: Let's make this an interesting problem.  How many maximal chains (chains of length 6) are there in P(A)?

Comment: @WilliamElliot each chain is defined by the order of removing the elements from $A$ itself, so the number is same as the number of bijections $A \to A$, i.e. $|A|! = 5! = 120$.